# yum conflicts with MySQL and MarioaDB

Tags: centos, yum

I run a MUD in C and I'm trying to compile it on a newer version of CentOS (7):

```
sql.h:1:25: fatal error: mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
```

So I try to install the MySQL packages

```
[user@server src]$ sudo yum install mysql++-devel
```

But I get many conflict errors:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql++-devel.x86_64 0:3.1.0-12.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-devel(x86-64) for package: mysql++-devel-3.1.0-12.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb101u-devel.x86_64 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-libs(x86-64) = 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-devel-10.1.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(openssl) for package: 1:mariadb101u-devel-10.1.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb101u-libs.x86_64 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-common(x86-64) = 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-libs-10.1.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-12.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: zlib-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: krb5-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-devel.x86_64 0:1.15.1-19.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libkadm5(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7 for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libverto-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcom_err-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: keyutils-libs-devel for package: krb5-devel-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64
---> Package mariadb101u-common.x86_64 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-config(x86-64) = 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-common-10.1.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.7-17.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package keyutils-libs-devel.x86_64 0:1.5.8-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libcom_err-devel.x86_64 0:1.42.9-12.el7_5 will be installed
---> Package libkadm5.x86_64 0:1.15.1-19.el7 will be installed
---> Package libselinux-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-12.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol-devel(x86-64) >= 2.5-6 for package: libselinux-devel-2.5-12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(libsepol) for package: libselinux-devel-2.5-12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(libpcre) for package: libselinux-devel-2.5-12.el7.x86_64
---> Package libverto-devel.x86_64 0:0.2.5-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package mariadb101u-config.x86_64 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libsepol-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-8.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package pcre-devel.x86_64 0:8.32-17.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: 1:mariadb101u-config-10.1.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mariadb-libs < 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7
--> Processing Conflict: 1:mariadb101u-common-10.1.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mariadb-libs < 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7
--> Processing Conflict: 1:mariadb101u-libs-10.1.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mariadb-libs < 1:10.1.32-1.ius.centos7
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mariadb101u-common conflicts with 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u-config conflicts with 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u-libs conflicts with 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Should I skip-broken or is there a better way to ensure I have the mysql C header files?

Comment: Is there a `mariadb-devel`? Have you tried `yum whatprovides '*/mysql/mysql.h'` to see what other packages provide this?

Comment: This looks like you have mixed repos for your MariaDB packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the MariaDB website, there's a FAQ that shows how to resolve the issue(s) you're running into. As I suspected, you've got a mishmash of RPMs installed that are not compatible with each other.

The FAQ is titled: [MariaDB Installation (Version 10.1.21) via RPMs on CentOS 7](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-installation-version-10121-via-rpms-on-centos-7/)

Comment: Helped me to install "KDE Plasma Workspace". Thanks! :)

Comment: What if `rpm -qa | grep mariadb-libs` yields nothing?

Comment: @User means it's not installed